# Ubuntu desktop settings menu replaced with one from ubuntu touch?

Tags: 13.10, ubuntu-touch

Okay so I have a really weird issue, my settings menu in Ubuntu 13.10 (desktop) has been replaced with what appears to be the one from Ubuntu touch. It even has a button labeled "About this phone". The only weird thing that may have caused this (that I can think of) is last night while setting up my computer to build android, I accidentally ran sudo apt-get purge java* to get rid of openjdk, instead of specifying openjdk. When I ran this it seemed like uninstalled a bit to much (and I am wondering if the normal menu got removed). That or I had the build environment setup for Ubuntu touch at one point too, which may have installed this??

Any ideas, on what might have caused this and/or how to fix it?

Here is a picture of it: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/108062965196949420402/albums/6004544167291557265

Sorry if I tagged this wrong it would not let me add the ubuntu-desktop tag.

Answer (score 0):

We tried a few things but here is the solution that worked. 
Run in terminal:

```
      sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

This should work. For some reason, on kd0hdf's computer gnome control center was uninstalled.

--
Techdude